# Installing Oracle 12c on Xenial

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am getting this error:

```
Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'.
```

Looking in the `make.log`, I see this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

Doing: `locate libpthread_nonshared`, I get this response:

```
/home/romio/libpthread_nonshared.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

which I guess means that the relevant lib is already on my computer.

But I don't know how to proceed from here. How do I tell the program to look the place with the library is? I come from Windows, so I'm yet very weak with Linux. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04

And I guess moving the package to the location oracle is searching must be a bad idea, since there might be other programs that use the package in its current location?

Comment: See https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/ and http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/03/31/how-to-install-oracle-12c-database-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-64bit-easy-guide/

Comment: Ubuntu is not supported by Oracle, so you must install Oracle on it either on your own or by following someone's "installation notes" which they chose to make public. Since you are very weak with Linux, I assume you are doing the latter. Which installation instructions are you following?

Comment: I personally used the dizwell instructions (see the link MT0 provided above). The instructions are for 16.04.1 and indeed I needed to edit a script to make it work for 16.04.2 but otherwise the installation worked exactly as advertised in the article.

Comment: For `libpthread-stubs` you can use this guide - http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/11/06/how-to-install-libpthread-stubs-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-32-64bit-linux/

Comment: I have tried several different instructions, which all eventually breaks at the above mentioned error.
I am not able to run the mendela script, as my version seems to be 16.04.02, and mendela only runs on 16.04.
I will try to proceed without the mandela however. Thanks

Comment: That's the wrong conclusion. Rather, edit the script, or maybe one of the text files it created - I don't remember exactly, find any references to 16.04 (or perhaps 16.04.1, I don't remember) and change them to 16.04.2 - happily, everything else will work just fine. That's what I did (again, as far as I recall).

Comment: Change line 122 of the Mandela script from `if [ "$VERCHECK" != "Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" ]; then` to `if [ "$VERCHECK" != "Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS" ]; then` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I finally made it, I installed oracle 12c on ubuntu 16.04.2 by following the link and suggestions in this thread. A shame I can't mark it as a solution, so others will know it

Answer (score 0):

You are using an unsupported linux distribution. You are pretty much on your own. I'd suggest to use a supported linux distribution.